# Moving virtual IP address

Tags: networking, server, haproxy

Something drive me crazy:
I ever installed Haproxy, to let it work I needed a virtual IP address.
Now I removed haproxy on both servers but still the virtual IP address is there and unable to remove.

The only I can see the eth0:0 is with webmin
Unable to remove with standard commando's or within webmin
if config -a show me only the real interface with loopback

Using sudo ip link set dev eth0 down and sudo apply netplan moved the virtual address to the other server.

How to remove this virtual interface?

help will be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

the answer:

sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf

remove net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind=1

sudo sysctl -p

sudo apt remove --purge keepalived

sudo apt autoremove

and problem is solved